# Quickblox for iOS: how do I extract locations only in 100 km area?

Tags: ios, quickblox

So in REST API I would do something like in the official tutorial:

```
curl -X GET \
-H "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0" \
-H "QB-Token: cc3598167f68a8e95b50a4fc6607cd3a8e7f043b" \
http://api.quickblox.com/geodata/find.xml?radius=100&current_position=90%3B90
```

How do I do something similar with iOS SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure

```
QBLGeoDataGetRequest *getRequest = [[QBLGeoDataGetRequest alloc] init];
getRequest.radius = 100;
getRequest.currentPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.55, -12.66);

[QBLocation geoDataWithRequest:getRequest delegate:self];
```